# Changing fonts within \titlecap

Tags: pdftex, formatting, titlecaps

I use the `\titlecap` macro from `titlecaps` package to convert text into titling caps. I would also like to make simple font style changes within the converted text.

The following example code does not compile:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlecaps}

\begin{document}

\Resetlcwords
\Addlcwords{for a is but and with of in as the etc on to if}
\titlecap{An interesting \textsf{corollary} is a good corollary}.

\end{document}
```

How can I make `\titlecap` work with simple font style changes?

**EDIT**

Steven's patch works for this simple example. However, in my actual use with the `titling` package in the mix, I still have a problem.

For example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\postdate{
    \centerline{\thetitle}
}

\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Resetlcwords
\Addlcwords{for a is but and with of in as the etc on to if}

\title{
    \titlecap{An \textbf{interesting} \textsf{c\"orollary} is the \"only good c\"orollary}
}
\author{First Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

compiles with "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup." error, fails to make the font changes, and produces extraneous characters:

[image: titlecaps with titling problem]

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: It used to work and is supposed to work for such cases.  As the maintainer, I will have to look into why it does not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, somewhere over time, the manner in which the `titlecaps` package was interacting with the `ifthen` package has changed...certain tokens that `titlecaps` was passing to `\ifthenelse` statements were now causing a fault.

I'm certainly not blaming `ifthen`, but I found that I needed to replace certain `\ifthenelse` calls with reformulated plain Tex `\ifx` calls.  In the process of debugging, I also realized that my extensive use of `\protected@edef` could be better served with selective expansions.

The bottom line was I really needed to revisit and revise the `titlecaps` package to clean it up.  Revisions have been made and uploaded to CTAN as version 1.3 [2022-04-12] (https://ctan.org/pkg/titlecaps).  Employing the revised version of the package, the following MWE works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlecaps}

\begin{document}

\Resetlcwords
\Addlcwords{for a is but and with of in as the etc on to if}
\titlecap{An interesting \textsf{c\"orollary} is the \"only good c\"orollary}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

As to the **EDIT**ED question, the OP's MWE has errors...apparently, one cannot use `\postdate` without also specifying `\predate` and `\date`.  When that is done, indeed the title is rendered properly by `titlecaps`, but the `\postdate`, specified as `\centerline{\thetitle}` end up scrogged.  The reason for this scrogging is that `\thetitle` ends up with a number of `\protect` macros inserted, which interact poorly with the titlecaps logic.

The solution is to save the `\titlecap` invocation into its own `\def`, such as `\mydef` given below, and use `\mydef` when you want it enacted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mydef{%
  \titlecap{An \textbf{interesting} \textsf{c\"orollary} is the \"only good
  c\"orollary}}
\usepackage{titling}
\predate{}
\date{}
\postdate{\centerline{\mydef}}

\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Resetlcwords
\Addlcwords{for a is but and with of in as the etc on to if}

\title{\mydef}
\author{First Author}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @Steven. I still experience a problem with `titling` package added to the mix, which I describe in my edit to OP.

Comment: @GorkemAksaray Your EDITED MWE has errors in it unrelated to titlecaps.  Nonetheless, I have addressed the issue in my **SUPPLEMENT**.

Comment: @GorkemAksaray The fix to the package has been uploaded to CTAN.